# how to rotate canvas with shape in HTML5.?

Tags: javascript, html

I have canvas on which i am drawing some HTM5 shapes(using context.fiiRect(x,y,w,h), context.strokeRect(x,y,w,h) etc). I want to rotate all the shape including canvas by 90 degree. Canvas is rotating but shapes are still on same position.... How can i do this thing for both CANVAS and shapes.

**EDIT**

HTML CODE:-

```
<body onload="draw();">
    <img style='display:none;'id='image' src="Robot.jpg"/>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="600" ></canvas>
    <canvas id="annCanvas" width="900" height="600" ></canvas>
    <div id="annoatation" >
       <input type="button" value="90°" onclick="rotate(90);">
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS CODE:-

```
#annoatation
{
  position: absolute;
}
#canvas
{
border: 1px solid black;
position: absolute;
}
#annCanvas
{
position: absolute;
}
```

JAVA SCRIPT CODE:-

```
function rotate(val)
{
    var image = document.getElementById('image');
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');



    canvas.setAttribute('width', image.height);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', image.width);
    canvasContext.rotate(90 * Math.PI / 180);
    canvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, -image.height);

    canvasContext.beginPath();
    canvasContext.strokeRect(50,50,200,200);
    canvasContext.stroke();


}
function draw()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var image1=new Image();
    image1.onload = function()
    {
        canvasContext.drawImage(image,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        canvasContext.beginPath();
        canvasContext.lineWidth=4;
        canvasContext.strokeRect(50,50,200,200);
        canvasContext.stroke();
    }
    image1.src='Robot.jpg';
}
```

I want to rotate rectangle on same position as it on 0 degree angle.

Comment: use `context.rotate` before drawing to the canvas.

Comment: Is CSS3 an option? You could use `transform:rotate(90deg)`: http://davidwalsh.name/css-transform-rotate

Comment: Thanks Yoshi.for reply.But actually i have already drawn some shapes then after i want to rotate canvas.Canvas is rotating perfectly but shapes remains on the same position. Would i have to draw that annotation again with rotation value.

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: I have added a sample code of my problem