# get rotating points of canvas after rotating the canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I am rotating an image with shape(e.g. Rectangle, Circle etc).

On rotation value 0, i can draw all my shapes on mouse move smoothly.

but on rotation value(e.g 90,180,270 means greater than o) :- On apply rotation i am rotating image and shapes simultaneously. But when i am trying to draw any shape, drawing is happen directionlessly. If am moving annotation from **left to right** then shape is drawing from **right to left**, from **top to bottom** to "bottom to top"..

I am rotating both canvas image as well as for shapes.

I have tried a lots from my side. But i am finding way to do this.

**Thanks In Advance**

Comment: @Yoshi your link is pointing to this question

Comment: Yoshi i think it gets duplicate.

Comment: @haynar you're right ;)  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562670/how-to-rotate-canvas-with-shape-in-html5) is the right one

Comment: So how can i resolve this proble.? because this is much important part of my project.

Comment: is there any solution from anyone. I am getting so confuse in this issue.